# How to populate field descriptions in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, import, schema, field

When linking to an external data source via ODBC (especially an AS/400), I often run into cryptic field names on the other side, where a data dictionary is not available. In the rare event that I'm able to get the field descriptions from the other db, I would like to be able to import them all at once, rather than copy/paste each description into the table design form one at a time.

I wasn't able to find this in the system tables, so I don't know where this metadata is stored. Any ideas on where it is, and whether it can be updated in batch?

Update: I managed to read the schema using the OpenSchema method (see code below), but this returns a read-only dataset, making it impossible for me to update the descriptions.

```
Function UpdateFieldDescriptions()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strDesc As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns)

While Not rs.EOF
    If Left(rs!table_name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        Debug.Print rs!table_name, rs!column_name, rs!Description
        strSQL = "SELECT Description " & _
            "FROM tblColumnDescriptions a " & _
            "WHERE a.Name = """ & rs!table_name & """ AND " & _
            "a.Column = """ & rs!column_name & """;"
        Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        While Not rs2.EOF
            strDesc = rs2.Fields(0)
            rs!Description = strDesc ' <---This generates an error
        Wend
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

rs.Update
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Use DAO instead of ADO:

```
Sub SetFieldDesc(TblName As String, FldName As String, Description As String)
Dim db As DAO.Database, td As DAO.TableDef, fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set td = db.TableDefs(TblName)
    Set fld = td.Fields(FldName)

    On Error Resume Next
    fld.Properties("Description") = Description
    If Err.Number = 3270 Then 'Property not found.'
        fld.Properties.Append fld.CreateProperty("Description", dbText, Description)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes that may help. The following shows field descriptions from adSchemaColumns.

```
   Function ListFieldDescriptions()
   ''List field descriptions
   Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, cn2 As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, rs2 As ADODB.Recordset

       Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

       Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, _
           Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "tablenamehere"))

       While Not rs.EOF
           Debug.Print rs!table_name; "   desc=  "; rs!Description
           Set rs2 = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
               Array(Empty, Empty, "" & rs!table_name & ""))
           While Not rs2.EOF
               Debug.Print "     " & rs2!Column_Name
               Debug.Print "     " & rs2!Data_Type
               Debug.Print "     " & rs2!Description
               Debug.Print "     " & rs2!Is_Nullable
               rs2.MoveNext
           Wend
       rs.MoveNext
       Wend
       rs.Close
       Set cn = Nothing

   End Function
```

From: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/ADO_Schemas

Comment: This isn't working - the OpenSchema call returns an empty recordset. I get rs.EOF immediately.

Perhaps this is due to the fact that my table is linked to an ODBC data source. But the table & field description properties are still stored locally in the Access db, so they must be somewhere...

Comment: I managed to get data back from OpenSchema by leaving the criteria field blank. I can read the column descriptions now. However, the OpenSchema method returns a static, read-only recordset, so I can't update the description. Any ideas how to get updates back into the schema?