# How do I include the field description for adding fields?

Tags: ms-access, field-description

I would like to programmatically add fields to an existing table and include data types and field descriptions.  I can add a fields with a data types with code:
ALTER TABLE my_existing_table ADD COLUMN  my_new_field Char(10);

Using object browser, I do not find a field Description property.  Just for reference, the field description is displayed in Design View and I can manually change it.

How do I include the field description for adding fields?

Comment: AFAIK you can't set it with Sql, but with DAO:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to populate field descriptions in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935207/how-to-populate-field-descriptions-in-ms-access)